# Sending data from a server to multiple clients

Tags: qt

I write the client and the server for sending messages. At the moment, the client sends a message to the server and receives it back.
But now I want to implement when several users are connected and communication occurs between them.
The project looks like this:

```
void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    // New connection
    Client *client = new Client(m_pBuffNetworkRead, m_pBuffNetworkWrite,this);
    if (!client->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor))
    {
        client->deleteLater();
        return;
    }

    m_clients.append(client);
}

Client::Client(BuffNetworkRead* pBuffNetworkRead, BuffNetworkWrite* pBuffNetworkWrite, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_pServerSocket(new QTcpSocket(this))
    , m_pBuffNetworkRead(pBuffNetworkRead)
    , m_pBuffNetworkWrite(pBuffNetworkWrite)
{
    // connect readyRead() to the slot that will take care of reading the data in
    connect(m_pServerSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Client::slotReadyRead);

    connect(m_pBuffNetworkWrite, &BuffNetworkWrite::signalReadyData, this, &Client::sendToClient);
}
```

Buffers are data objects that the client reads or writes.
As you can see, the server receives a connection, gives the socket to the client, and it connects. It has a sendToClient method inside which, when new data appears, sends it to the network.

And now the question is: how do I understand the sendToClient method should not be on the client, but on the server? Should he send data? Then the Client object must transfer some data to the MyServer so that it can work with all clients and decide to whom and what should be transferred? Can you please explain how it should work? Or maybe this particular function as an example is somewhere in the internet?